# Chrome Extensions Content-Security-Policy

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I have the need in my extension to dynamically load code . I wrote this to load it -

```
    var se = document.createElement('script');
se.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
se.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(se);
```

And this is my security policy in manifest.js -

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

This throws a javascript error -

```
 "Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe eval'"
```

My question is - Why isn't it relaxed ? I specifically added the line in manifest to allow unsafe evals .

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's your use of `eval` that is causing the error.  It appears you're violating the policy against executing inline JavaScript, by injecting `<script>` blocks into the `head` of your document.

According to the documentation on [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html):

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. < button onclick='...'>).

Also note:

> **Inline Script**
>
> There is no mechanism for relaxing the restriction against executing inline JavaScript. In particular, setting a script policy that includes 'unsafe-inline' will have no effect.

Instead of placing your code inline you'll have to come up with an approach that utilizes external `js` files to accomplish whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: It looks like those policy's are delimited by semicolons, and the error message probably just extracts from your `manifest.json` the particular policy that is in violation. In this case, `script-src` along with its settings `'self'` and `unsafe-eval`.

Comment: You could test out my answer by removing all occurrences of `eval` from you inline script and seeing if you get the same error. Another option is to just try using your code above to inject some arbitrary JavaScript, e.g. a `function` that only calls `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your manifest.json, worked for me.

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```